# PHP array refuses to treat numeric string as number value

Tags: php, xml, arrays, curl, var

I am trying to get a PHP array output into a just number PHP variable so I can do arithmetic on it and then store it globally for use in a shopping cart.

Here is the code generating and manipulating the array:

```
<?php
function ups($dest_zip,$service,$weight,$length,$width,$height) {
$AccessLicenseNumber = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'; // Your license number
$UserId = 'XXXXXXXX'; // Username
$Password = 'XXXXXXXX'; // Password
$PostalCode = 'XXXXXX'; // Zipcode you are shipping FROM
$ShipperNumber = 'XXXXX'; // Your UPS shipper number

    $data ="<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
    <AccessRequest xml:lang=\"en-US\">
        <AccessLicenseNumber>$AccessLicenseNumber</AccessLicenseNumber>
        <UserId>$UserId</UserId>
        <Password>$Password</Password>
    </AccessRequest>
    <?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
    <RatingServiceSelectionRequest xml:lang=\"en-US\">
        <Request>
            <TransactionReference>
                <CustomerContext>Bare Bones Rate Request</CustomerContext>
                <XpciVersion>1.0001</XpciVersion>
            </TransactionReference>
            <RequestAction>Rate</RequestAction>
            <RequestOption>Rate</RequestOption>
        </Request>
    <PickupType>
        <Code>01</Code>
    </PickupType>
    <Shipment>
        <Shipper>
            <Address>
                <PostalCode>$PostalCode</PostalCode>
                <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
            </Address>
        <ShipperNumber>$ShipperNumber</ShipperNumber>
        </Shipper>
        <ShipTo>
            <Address>
                <PostalCode>$dest_zip</PostalCode>
                <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
            <ResidentialAddressIndicator/>
            </Address>
        </ShipTo>
        <ShipFrom>
            <Address>
                <PostalCode>$PostalCode</PostalCode>
                <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
            </Address>
        </ShipFrom>
        <Service>
            <Code>$service</Code>
        </Service>
        <Package>
            <PackagingType>
                <Code>02</Code>
            </PackagingType>
            <Dimensions>
                <UnitOfMeasurement>
                    <Code>IN</Code>
                </UnitOfMeasurement>
                <Length>$length</Length>
                <Width>$width</Width>
                <Height>$height</Height>
            </Dimensions>
            <PackageWeight>
                <UnitOfMeasurement>
                    <Code>LBS</Code>
                </UnitOfMeasurement>
                <Weight>$weight</Weight>
            </PackageWeight>
        </Package>
    </Shipment>
    </RatingServiceSelectionRequest>";
    $ch = curl_init("https://www.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Rate");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
    $result=curl_exec ($ch);        
   $upsout = (explode('USD', $result, 15));    
    $handling = $upsout[3];
   echo "<br><br>Shipping: $";
    echo $handling; 
   echo " USD<br><br>";       
   curl_close($ch);
   var_dump( $handling);
// print_r ($upsout);}?>
```

The output of $handling is always a number in either 00.00 or 000.00 format, with the zeroes being numbers of course. I really need this to be able to work in arithmetic functions and be able to be stored for use as a number.

I know it isn't working becuase if I do

```
$test = $handling *2;
echo $test;
```

I get "0" as the output, not double whatever $handling is...

EDIT:

If i run var_dump( htmlentities( $handling));

the output is:

string(222) "33.35"

If I run var_dump( $handling);

the output is

string(168) "33.35"

SO.... I need to find a way to parse the junk out of this array entry so I can manipulate it algebraically.

Comment: try replace dot with comma before casting to integer

Comment: Post the output of `var_dump( $handling);`

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($handling);` right before your `$test` lines? I just wanna make sure `$handling` actually has a value.

Comment: It sounds as if you're getting back a float, rather than an int.  try (float)$handling

Comment: Also you are sending `$data` in postfields but your function does not have such variable. Make sure you are creating correct post data.

Comment: var_dump( $handling); output is "string(168) "33.35" without the quotes of course...

Comment: Add the output of `var_dump( htmlentites( $handling));` into your question. You'll see why it's not working when you see that.

Comment: can you update your code above to include the $data content.  Just remove your developer access key.  Otherwise, publish the XML that you are posting as a request and remove your access key.

Comment: I updated the code with the $data content as requested. I'll try (float)$handling like you suggested.

Comment: float didn't help, still returns 0 when used in math functions... thank you for the help so far.

Comment: @jG - I've already told you what your problem is - Your string has crap in it that's not just a number. If you don't put the output of `var_dump( htmlentites( $handling));` into your question, nobody has no idea what other crap is in your string. You can easily tell by posting what I just said, or viewing the source of the PHP page  you're working with in your browser.

Comment: NickB- I just tried that, and it gave an error -Fatal error: Call to undefined function htmlentites() in /home/public_html/ups2.php on line 114. Any suggestions? I haven't used that function before, so I don't know if I am using it correctly. I posted it just as you have it in a php block.

Comment: @jG There was a typo in nickb's answer; the method you are looking for is [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities).

Comment: oh man I can't believe i didn't notice the misspelling of entities... I'll give that a shot.

Comment: I will edit the question to better describe the issue. Output from htmlentities is string(222) "</CurrencyCode><MonetaryValue>33.35</MonetaryValue></TotalCharges><GuaranteedDaysToDelivery/><ScheduledDeliveryTime/><RatedPackage><TransportationCharges><CurrencyCode>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm betting your string has HTML tags in it, which is why you're getting this `var_dump()`:

```
string(168) "33.35"
```

The first number means your string is 168 characters in length, while `33.35` takes up 5 characters. So there's something else in there that's not just a number.

One of these solutions will work, but I can't be sure of what the string actually looks like, so I'm throwing out a bunch of ideas.

```
$haystack0 = strip_tags( $haystack); 
echo '0. ' . $haystack0 * 2; echo "<br />\n";

$haystack1 = trim( strip_tags( $haystack)); 
echo '1. ' . $haystack1 * 2; echo "<br />\n";

preg_match( '/\b(\d+\.\d+)\b/', $haystack, $match);
$haystack2 = $match[1];
echo '2. ' . $haystack2 * 2; echo "<br />\n";

$haystack3 = preg_replace( '/[^\d\.]+/', '', $haystack); 
echo '3. ' . $haystack3 * 2; echo "<br />\n";
```

**Edit:** Here is the actual string:

```
string(222) "</CurrencyCode><MonetaryValue>33.35</MonetaryValue></TotalCharges><GuaranteedDaysToDelivery/><ScheduledDeliveryTime/><RatedPackage><TransportationCharges><CurrencyCode>"
```

So, we put that into `$haystack` and get rid of the XML tags:

```
$haystack = "</CurrencyCode><MonetaryValue>33.35</MonetaryValue></TotalCharges><GuaranteedDaysToDelivery/><ScheduledDeliveryTime/><RatedPackage><TransportationCharges><CurrencyCode>";
$haystack = strip_tags( $haystack);
var_dump( $haystack);
```

And we get [as output](http://codepad.org/dQ7aklrP):

```
 string(5) "33.35"
```

So, now, we can multiply it by two, [and get](http://codepad.org/6F1Fqg3S):

```
 float(66.7)
```

Problem solved!

Comment: Nice catch . . . it's probably XML with a <value> node and some other info in there . . .

Comment: Here is the output of the original XML, without being turned into an array:  Bare Bones Rate Request1.00011Success03Your invoice may vary from the displayed reference ratesLBS60.0USD33.35USD0.00USD33.35USD33.35USD0.00USD33.3560.0LBS60.0

Comment: So no HTML tags, but loads of text... That is why I made it into an array delimited by "USD" and then grabbed the third cell, which is just 5 digits, 33.35 in this case. Does seeing the string help narrow the options you brought up?

Comment: @jG - The problem is just what I suspected, and my first proposed solution (#0) worked from my original answer. The loads of text is XML, not HTML, but can be removed the same way as HTML. You can see in my updated answer that the number is now correctly multiplied.

Comment: @jG - You're getting an XML response.  To verify this, you could do a 'echo $result' and view the source, run the script from the command line, or 'echo( htmlentities($result) )'.  The fact that you explode on 'USD' doesn't remove all the XML markup, and the fact that it's not showing when you print doesn't mean it's not there.

Comment: @jG - it's also a bad idea to try to manually fudge XML output to get what you want . . . you should probably research things like [xml_parse_into_struct](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php) or [simpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Comment: Just getting back to this, thank you for the thorough description of the issue I caused and how to resolve it. I will implement your solution and comment back before closing the question as solved. Thanks again.

Comment: Code implemented. Works great! Thank you so much nickb!

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and works fine, but you'd lose the decimal values:

```
<?php
$handling = '12.24';

echo intval($handling) * 2; // prints 24
echo floatval($handling) * 2; // prints 24.48

?>
```

To solve your problem you should wrap $handling with floatval() function:

```
<?php function ups($dest_zip,$service,$weight,$length,$width,$height)
    </RatingServiceSelectionRequest>";
    $ch = curl_init("https://www.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Rate");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
    $result=curl_exec ($ch);        
    $upsout = (explode('USD', $result, 15));    
    $handling = floatval($upsout[3]);  // <--- recommend wrap here if you need to use variable later in math
    echo "<br><br>Shipping: $";
    echo $handling;
    echo " USD<br><br>";       
    curl_close($ch);
    // print_r ($upsout);}
 ?>
```

Comment: This is irrelevant in the context it is in. If I gave you the file locations and you ran it on the actual server with live values from the API this would mean something... that is where my problem is : ( sorry

Comment: j G are you saying you tried to change your handling variable before performing math adding floatval($handling) * 2 and it did not work?  If the *2 math was just your test, then all you need to do in your code is wrap $handling with floatval($handling) in the line where you echo it.

Comment: see my edit above using your code as example.  if you need the amount for math later which you haven't showed us, then wrap the api response value.  otherwise you could either wrap the $handling during echo or above.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Thinking about this more, are you sure that your sample code there with $test actually happens that way?  [Type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) should allow you to multiply the string times a number and return a number.  What happens if you change your test line of your sample code to:

```
print "handling is $handling \n calculated value is $test";
```

**Original:** As this appears to be a cost that you're getting back from UPS, it most likely won't be an integer as there'll be cents (your mentioning that the value is of the form `00.00` or `000.00` seems to confirm this as well).

Because of that, you'll want to turn it into a float, using one of these methods:

```
$test = (float)$handling * 2;
$test2 = floatval($handling) * 2;
```

Comment: From looking at documentation, I think it'll need to be `2.0` or it might round the number depending on the version of PHP.

Comment: @Ally see my code below and I just tested and works fine with 2, not needing 2.0

Comment: @MikeS. Yeah, looks like it only rounded in old versions of PHP. I'm unable to test anything right now, but thank you for doing so.

Comment: @ally Any links to the doc you're referring to?  I'd be curious to learn more . . .

Comment: @ernie I already closed the page so I don't remember exactly which comment it was on the doc, but it was a fair ways down [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)